# C++ Segmentation fault from pointer backtrace

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am currently getting a seg fault and its starting at what I believe to be a line in main, after doing a backtrace in gdb, I can basically pinpoint it but I am not sure what needs to change. here are the places I am seeing it in order:

First in main:

```
DeckOps *deck = new DeckOps(filename);
```

I believe is the line that is causing it, backtrace also includes

```
class DeckOps{
 public:
  DeckOps(string filename);
  ~DeckOps();

 private:
  dlist *deck;
}
```

and then the .cpp file

```
DeckOps::DeckOps(string filename){

  ifstream inF;

  inF.open(filename.c_str());

  if (inF.fail()){
    cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }
  int deckcount = 28;
  int card;
  for(int i = 0; i <= deckcount; i++){
    inF >> card;
    deck->insertRear(card);
  }
  inF.close();
}
```

and then finally the last place

```
void dlist::insertRear(int d){
  LinkNode *link = new LinkNode();
  int *nd = new int();
  *nd = d;
  link->data= nd;

  if(first == 0){
    first = last = link;
    return;
  }
  last->next = link;
  link->prev = last;
  last = link;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem, but why create an object like this: `DeckOps *deck = new DeckOps(filename);` Why not `DeckOps deck(filename);` - C++ is not Java.

Comment: I agree with Neil, try to use `new` as little as possible. It will give you a speed increase and no manual memory management.

Comment: thats the way i learned, i tried out you said to do it and that wasn't working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `DeckOps::DeckOps`, the line

```
deck->insertRear(card);
```

is probably causing the segfault. `deck` is a pointer but you never initialize it to anything (like `deck = new dlist` or whatever) so it points to a random location in memory (or is initialized to `0` depending on your compiler) and you're trying to use the random memory it's pointing to (or dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, again depending on your compiler), causing a segfault. You'll need to do that at the top of the constructor before you can use it.

If you fix that and it still has a segfault, then it had more than one problem in the first place, probably somewhere in the `dlist` code.

Comment: nope that fixed it! thanks! i should of realized that i forgot to do that. now i need to know if there is a way i could select a whole section of my linked list, and swap it with another section.

Comment: @adsderek that should be as simple as manipulating 3 pointers. Please mark this answer as _the_ answer if it solved your question by clicking the check mark underneath the two arrows to the top left of this answer.

Comment: would you care to elaborate? I am not really sure where to start on this problem. an idea I have is to create a function in my list class that can select a range of linknodes , say i need all the nodes below a specific one, and all the nodes above another specific one to switch places. and what if i have to input them in front of another, say just ahead of the rear.

Comment: i know i will need a find function, and some sort of swap function, if it can be universal(to swap either a group of link nodes, or just one with another)

Comment: @adsderek look at it this way: To swap one node with another, you do basically this, where `pre->next` points to `n1` and you want to swap `n1` with `n2`: `n1->next = n2->next; n2->next = n1; pre->next = n2;`. So if you want to swap two groups of nodes (presuming they don't overlap) then you just treat them the same. Here is a picture that may help: http://i.imgur.com/p9jtc.png How you select the groups is up to you. Also, as you said, it might be good to implement your `swap-one-with-one` function as a call to the `swap-two-groups` function, with the groups being just the two single nodes.